# How to use English Localized values for the webservice when I choose Other language

Tags: android, web-services, localization

I am developing an application which will be work in **Turkish** language. When I run the app in English language the app is working fine. Now when I am checking the app in Turkish language there are getting error results.

I have an array resources

```
 <string-array name="pensionArr">// English(values-en)
    <item>monthly</item>
    <item>yearly</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="pensionArr"> // Turkish(values-tr)
    <item>aylık</item>
    <item>yıllık</item>
</string-array>
```

I set this array in spinner.

```
adapterPension = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.pensionArr, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Now I am sending the selected value from this spinner to web service. There i am comparing the value in English.

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pension_type",_pensiontype));
```

When I am trying to print the value `_pensiontype`. the value printing in console is like this

```
yıllık//====> yearly in English.
```

So the value is not comparing in the web service. So here is my question how to use **English** values even I choose **Turkish**. Is there any way for this.

**Edit**: Data from spinner is

```
 _pensiontype=pensionTypeDrpgetSelectedItem().toString();
```

Pls Help me......

Comment: how do you get your data from the spinner?

Comment: @lenik, check the edited question once..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very tricky situation. Finally I search it in many websites and find a solution

Maintain the array in the server side as

```
String[] arr = new String{"monthly","yearly"};
```

after setting the resource array to the spinner as

```
adapterPension = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.pensionArr, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Now I am sending the position of the selected item to the server as

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pension_type",Integer.toString(pensionDrp.getSelectedItemPosition())));
```

Now I am getting the position of array at server side. so Using index instead of value directly.

works fine..

Answer (score 0):

The matter is with the name of the folder. The main folder has name "values"(usually for English). The name of your folder should be: "values-tr". The solution is:
1. Create folder in /res folder with the name "values-tr". 
2. Create file strings.xml in it
3. Put your constants in your new file

Comment: ya, I have two separate folders(values-en, values-tr)

Comment: If your phone has turkish localization it will use strings file from folder values-tr. You'll wil have to copy-paste all the constants, no matter if you'll use them or not.

Answer (score 0):

please, use:

```
Spinner.getSelectedItemId() or
Spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()
```

to get an index of the selected item, and use this index to choose English string to be sent to the server. `Spinner` still may be populated with the localized strings, but the server data stays always in English (or you may send index as a number, if you like)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I too think as like this. But there are so many of arrays like this.So I need to change from my side. Is it possible